# Filtering with Let

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have inherited an app with the following tblTradeSpends table:

```
ID   PromoID    Customer    LineOfBusiness     DealYear    VersionDate
1    p100       200         SCF                2013        2/23/2013
2    p101       200         SCF                2013        2/23/2013
3    p102       200         SCF                2013        2/23/2013
4    p103       200         SCF                2013        2/23/2013
5    p100       200         SCF                2013        3/23/2013
6    p101       200         SCF                2013        3/23/2013
7    p102       200         SCF                2013        3/23/2013
```

The combination of Customer, LineOfBusiness, DealYear and VersionDate make up the concept of a "Version" for a block of deals. The data above describes two Versions with the following Promo IDs:

```
Version 1 (Created 2/23/2013): p100, p101, p102, p103

Version 2 (Created 3/23/2013): p100, p101, p102
```

So, when this block of deals was updated, the deal with PromoID `p103` was removed.

I have a screen where I want to display only the latest Version for a block of deals. I came up with the following, which I thought was working but actually has a bug in it:

```
var records = from t in query
let maxversion =
            (from v in _context.tblTradeSpends
            where v.PromoID == t.PromoID
            select v.VersionDate).Max()
where t.PlanType == "Planner" &&
t.VersionDate == maxversion
select t
```

Now, the `p103` deal was removed in the latest version by the salesman, but because it possesses the maximum date for any deal with its promo ID, it is being displayed.

```
ID   PromoID    Customer    LineOfBusiness     DealYear    VersionDate
4    p103       200         SCF                2013        2/23/2013
5    p100       200         SCF                2013        3/23/2013
6    p101       200         SCF                2013        3/23/2013
7    p102       200         SCF                2013        3/23/2013
```

I do not want `p103` in this resultset. How can I update my query so that I only display records with the latest VersionDate for the unique combination of Customer, LineOfBusiness, and DealYear?

**UPDATE**

If it doesn't muddy the waters too much, in SQL I would group by Customer#, LineOfBusiness, and DealYear, determine the max VersionDate for the group, and then use that date for my filter. I'm unsure how to do the same here.

Comment: Does this p103 row has a value that is not common to the other results? And you only want to remove the row p103 in the resultset right?

Comment: I want to remove any record that doesn't have the version date equal to the maximum version date of any other record that has the same Customer #, LineOfBusiness, and DealYear. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but your problem now is that p103 has a VersionDate that is maximumversion thus it is being included in the list. And what is MaxVersion in here is it 3/23/2013?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis The max VersionDate for the sample I provided is 3/23/2013, as that is the latest `VersionDate` for the unique combination of records with Customer# = 200, LineOfBusiness = SCF, and DealYear = 2013.

Comment: @ChrisHardie Regarding your update, if you get the max date for each group, you will still select `p103`.

Comment: @Trickery Would I? The max VersionDate for the group would be March 23, 2013. The VersionDate of p103 is Feb. 23, 2013. Wouldn't that be enough to filter it out?

Comment: @ChrisHardie Mmm.. You want the max date per each unique combo of `Customer`, `LineOfBusiness` and `DealYear`. And then you want all the records within that group with the max date? I updated my answer, maybe I got it right this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    var records = from t in query
    let maxversion =
            (from v in _context.tblTradeSpends
            where v.Customer == t.Customer
            && v.LineOfBusiness == t.LineOfBusiness
            && v.DealYear == t.DealYear
            select v.VersionDate).Max()
    where t.PlanType == "Planner" &&
    t.VersionDate == maxversion
    select t
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if I understood correctly, p103 is removed because its `VersionDate` is not the max in the table. So this means that when the table has new `VersionDate`s, for example, `4/23/2013`, all records that don't have this date should be ignored?

```
ID   PromoID    Customer    LineOfBusiness     DealYear    VersionDate
1    p103       200         SCF                2013        2/23/2013  // Deprecated
2    p102       200         SCF                2013        2/23/2013  // Deprecated
3    p102       200         SCF                2013        3/23/2013
```

Sounds like you just need the max `VersionDate` of the table, and all records that have it. Correct?

```
var records = from t in query
    let maxversion =
        (from v in _context.tblTradeSpends
        where v.Customer == t.Customer &&
              v.LineOfBusiness == t.LineOfBusiness &&
              v.DealYear == t.DealYear
        select v.VersionDate).Max()
    where t.PlanType == "Planner" &&
    t.VersionDate == maxversion 
    select t
```

Comment: No, I don't need the max VersionDate of the table, as we have thousands of blocks of deals, I need the max VersionDate for each unique combination of Customer#, LineOfBusiness, and DealYear. The sample data I provided was an infinitely small subset I used for trying to clarify my question.

Comment: Bang on, but the other guy just beat you to the punch with the identical query. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This works for Linq to objects, not sure about using with Linq2SQL/EF

```
var records = (from t in _context.tblTradeSpends
       where t.PlanType == "Planner"
       group t by new { t.Customer, t.LineOfBusiness, t.DealYear } into g
       let maxVersion = g.Max(promo => promo.VersionDate)
       select g.Where(p => p.VersionDate == maxVersion)).SelectMany(s => s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that since you use `t` in your subquery, there is a `maxversion` for each line, not one for the whole thing. You need to select the max version out of the results you want. This might work:

```
var query = query.Where(t => t.PlanType == "Planner");
var records = from t in query
  let maxversion =
            (from v in query
            select v.VersionDate).Max()
  where t.VersionDate == maxversion
  select t;
```

Comment: Would that not just get me the maximum version date for the table? That date would not be applicable to most blocks of deals. The more I think about it, the more I believe I need to group by Customer#, LineOfBusiness and DealYear.